# Populate a mutableArray with objects from dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am having trouble populating an array of objects (employee names) from a group of NSDictionaries (each one representing an individual employee) which are inside another NSDictionary *dictionary (personnel). The key for each sub Dictionary is an employee ID.

I might well be coming at this from a completely wrong direction, i am very much a newbie but from what i have read it should be something like this , i have managed to get as far as a pName (employee name) from each sub Dictionary, all be it fleetingly. I just can't get the pNames added into MutableArray *names.

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated ...

```
  int i, count;
  id key, value;

  keys = [dictionary allKeys];
  count = [keys count];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
   key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
   value = [dictionary objectForKey: key];
   NSLog (@"value:%@", value); 

   NSString *pName = [value objectForKey:@"personName"];
   NSLog (@"pName:%@", pName);// the debugger shows the correct pName with each loop

   [names addObject:pName];// this is wrong and i don't know why
  }
   NSLog (@"names:%@", names);// in the debugger names (null)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future please take the time to format the code in your question appropriately (using the "{}" editor control).

Comment: Any chance you could update your question with a slightly more fleshed out code sample? (One that shows how the names NSMutableArray is initialised, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't creating an array object to put your names in. There needs to be code like this:

```
names = [NSMutableArray array];
```

... before the start of the loop. That creates an empty mutable array.

Comment: thank you very much .. i appreciate you solving such an elementary issue.

Comment: +1 Damn. There was me thinking he'd simply omitted that part of the code sample. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using [collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE), specifically the [`@unionOfObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW2) operator:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[[personnel allValues] 
                            valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.personName"] 
                            mutableCopy];
```

Note that `names` will be owned by the method (its retain count is 1), but the interim arrays (`[personnel allValues]` and the one created by `valueForKeyPath:`) are autoreleased and not owned by the method.

For some reason (possibly because key names beginning with "@" are special in [`valueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ), and thus `valueForKeyPath:` wouldn't be equivalent to a sequence of calls to `valueForKey:`), `NSDictionary` doesn't have a `valueForKeyPath:` method, so you first need to convert it to an array using `allValues`. Alternatively, you could implement `valueForKeyPath:` in a category, perhaps starting from [GnuStep's](http://gnustep-base.sourcearchive.com/lines/1.20.0/NSArray_8m-source.html#l01392) or [cocotron's](http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSKeyValueCoding/NSArray%2BKVC.m#64) (which doesn't actually support `@unionOfObjects`, but allows for easy extension by defining a `_kvo_operator_unionOfObjects:` method).